# Salesforce marketing cloud sdk analytics not working

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are using 'MarketingCloudSDK', version '7.5.0'. Recently, we discovered that the SDK is not sending events. It has stopped sending events for the past year. I tested the SDK configuration in Xcode, and it does not throw any errors. Could you kindly tell us what the problem is and how to address it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the analytics is enabled while configuring the SDK.
This should trigger calls for analytics. Also, 7.5.0 is released 3 years back, and there are lot of version updates that can be checked here [https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/#:~:text=Prior%20Release%20Documentation-,Releases,-Version%208.1.2](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/#:%7E:text=Prior%20Release%20Documentation-,Releases,-Version%208.1.2) in the release notes.

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: Hey, Prakashini Pattabiraman. Thanks for responding. It was quite useful. I verified the analytics, and they were enabled during the SDK configuration. So we decided to upgrade the SDK to the current version to check if it works, but we're not sure how to test whether or not events are triggering. Could you please provide us with more details on how to test so that we can confirm events are triggering successfully?

Comment: Hi , Please check in the SDK state, analytics enabled should be present in the state. Also, in debug mode, please check console logs, you should see a call to analytics while backgrounding or foregrounding the SDK.

Comment: Hey, Prakashini Pattabiraman. Thanks for providing further information. Please see below for the SDK state log and a few additional logs.

\"Analytics Details\" : {\n    \"useLegacyPiIdentifier\" : false,\n    \"PiIdentifier\" : \"Not Set\",\n    \"PIAnalyticsEnabled\" : true,\n    \"ETAnalyticsEnabled\" : true\n  }

Comment: blocking MarketingCloudSDKMigration via control channel payload
{ nodes =     ( {  items =  { blocked = 0; } name = blocked; version = 1; }, { items =             ( ); name = inAppMessages; version = 1; }, { items = ( ); name = triggers; version = 1; },  { items = { inbox = 0; }; name = pushFeaturesInUse; version = 1; }, { items =          { endpoints = ( ); event = { activeEvents = ( ); }; inApp = {  gateEventProcessingMs = 1000; };  };  name = appConfig;  version = 1; } ); }
MarketingCloudSDKMigration.m
line: 547

Comment: message response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000046e540> { URL: https://mc757tzlzt3jdcs9r51jfd2hrt14.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/26ea57be-f8f3-4688-b517-4d373005c262/message/?deviceid=30106AEA-C5E1-49F9-838E-58F8D63204D9&messagetype=8&contenttype=2 }

Comment: { Status Code: 200, Headers { } message response data:{"count":0,"page":0,"pageSize":0,"links":{},"messages":[]}

Comment: Can you suggest me whether there is anything not right by looking at the logs?

Comment: Hi ,Please create a support ticket if you are still unable to get the analytics working.